# How can I get a win 7 batch file to output a list of unique filename prefixes?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I have the following files in a folder

```
MyDocuments 2014-10-10.zip
MyDocuments 2014-10-09.zip
MyPictures 2014-10-10.zip
MyPictures 2014-10-09.zip
```

Ideally I would like the output to show

```
MyDocuments
MyPictures
```

Comment: sorry, there should be a new line after each file name.  I did type them in the question...

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SU, we're not a script writing service, but we can help with specific problems you may be having. What have you got so far, and where exactly are you getting stuck implementing your script?

Comment: hi, thanks and sorry... I've been trying to work with manipulating the output of dir /B but I've scratched that.  I'm currently restarting, using a loop and will post something when I've got it running or sort of

Comment: @s1m Indicating in your question what you've tried (like `dir /b`) and what happened (the good and bad) is part of asking good questions on Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FOR /F to break each name at the first space, and use environment variables to keep track of which names have been discovered.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Clear any existing _ variables
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set _ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="

:: Discover and list all unique file prefixes
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d') do if not defined _%%F (
  echo %%F
  set "_%%F=1"
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks but I'm getting "2> was unexpected at this time." The discover bit works tho - THANK YOU!!

Comment: @s1m - Yes, I forgot to escape the redirection within the IN() clause. All fixed now.

Comment: Sir, you are truly awesome! thank you so much

Comment: @s1m - If you feel an answer fully answers your question, then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner. Only one answer may be accepted per question.